# How to filter a list of employees based on whether or not the Employees are working overtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have been trying really hard to create a list of employees and find who have worked over time and add them to the list.

But i really can't.

Can you help me solve this?

please check the image. 
thanks

```
public class Employee
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public double HourlyWage { get; set; }
    public double HoursPerMonth { get; set; }


    public double GetMonthlyPay()
    {

        double overTimeHours= HoursPerMonth - 150;
        double pay;

        if(overTimeHours <= 0)
        {
            pay = HourlyWage * HoursPerMonth;
        }
        else
        {
            pay = (150 * HourlyWage) + (overTimeHours * HourlyWage * 1.5);
        }
        return pay;
        strong text
```

{this question was answered, i am just editing the question. appearently it was off topic.}

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], especially the part about "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```cs
class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double HourlyWage { get; set; }
    public int HoursPerMonth { get; set; }

    public double GetMonthlyPay()
    {
        int overtimeHours = HoursPerMonth - 150;
        double pay;

        if (overtimeHours <= 0)
        {
            pay = HoursPerMonth * HourlyWage;
        }
        else
        {
            pay = (150 * HourlyWage) + ( overtimeHours * HourlyWage * 1.5);

        }

        return pay;
    }
}


class EmployeeService {
    public List<Employee> FilterEmployeesBasedOnOverTime(List<Employee> employees, bool hasOvertime = false)
    {
        return employees.Where(e => hasOvertime ? e.HoursPerMonth > 150 : e.HoursPerMonth <= 150).ToList();
    }

    public double GetTotalMonthlyExpense(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        return employees.Sum(e => e.GetMonthlyPay());
    }
}
```

I hope this solution suits your need.

Comment: Thanks Claudiom248, i tried hours to solve it, and i never thought it could be solved this way. 
appreciate your help. 
can you explain a little about the method FIlterEmployeesBasedOneOverTime?

Comment: Hello Jalil, I'm glad to have been useful. What the code does is: 
if the flag hasOvertime is true, the applied filter will be (e.HoursPerMonth > 150) else it will be (e.HoursPerMonth <= 150). For every employee on the list, a check will be made following those criteria. So, when the flag is true, it will return all the employees that have worked more than 150 hours, else all the employees that have not worked more than 150 hours will returned.

Comment: great explaination, thanks again,

Comment: Hi again Can you Help me with one more thing?

Comment: Hi again Can you Help me with one more thing? Create a controller class which exposes three HTTP endpoints:
api/employees (GET)

Returning a list of all employees. Given a boolean parameter ‘hasOvertime’, the endpoint should be able to filter the list of Employees using the EmployeeService.  E.g.: api/employees?hasOvertime=true.

api/employees (POST)
Taking an Employee object in the request body and storing it in the list of employees.
api/payments (GET)
Returning the sum of all monthly payments. Similar to the other GET method, you should be able to filter by overtime,